# Package to use for searching in react

Tags: reactjs

want to do search in react with **Api** call like google search with options package name
and where to find it

i have tried to use the html directly by creating components my self but does not work as i want and don't want to waste time in it if there is package to do it fast would be appreciated

Comment: can you please post what you have tried in a codesandbox so we can see how to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use react-bootstrap-typeahead
from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead
it can be used to search and give you the options to select from options withs well with api